# Error when trying to archive xcode project

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, archive

My project runs fine when I run it using the iPhone simulator, and when I run it on a device. When I try to archive it for submission, I get this error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This was directly before the error and I'm not sure if it's related:

```
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/dog94a/Google Drive/Capstone/Backups/Approach/Approach/GMaps/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps     for architecture armv7s
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the `Debug` build configuration is to only build the active architecture (`Build Active Architecture Only` build setting is `YES`).  This is not the case for the `Release` build configuration, which will build all architectures supported by your `Valid Architectures` build setting.  What this means is that you're likely not targeting an `armv7s` device during your `Debug` builds (iPhone 5, latest iPad, etc), so you're not attempting to build that architecture until you do an archive which uses the `Release` build configuration by default.

The error indicates that your project is configured to create a binary that has `armv7s` instructions for when it runs on devices of that type, but the `GoogleMaps.framework` binary you're trying to link against was not built with an `armv7s` slice.  To fix this, you either have to update to the latest version of the `GoogleMaps.framework` and hope they built it with `armv7s` enabled, or remove `armv7s` from your `Valid Architectures` build setting (obviously the former is preferable).

Answer (score 0):

Once I have included a framework and at compile time nagged the linker for armv7. Now you have armv7s, which is the iphone5?

Solution to my problem it was: remove all files from that framework.
Compile that framework ( double check at Valid architectures settings to be there the desired architecture
Re-add the newly compiled framework.

Try and maybe it helps or even solve your problem too!